# How to solve this in an efficient way with optimum time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, performance, logic

Given a set of N numbers in an array. Given Q queries. Each Query contains 1 number x.

For each query, you need to add x to each element of the array and then report the sum of absolute values in the array.

Note : Changes to the array are permanent. See Sample for more clarification.

Input Format

First line contains N , number of elements in the array. 
Next line contains N space separated integers of the array. 
Next line contains Q(number of queries). 
Next line contains Q space separated integers(the number x).

Output Format

For each query , output the sum in a newline.

Constraints
1 ≤ N ≤ 500000
1 ≤ Q ≤ 500000
-2000 ≤ number in each Query ≤ 2000
-2000 ≤ value of the array element ≤ 2000

Sample Input

3
-1  2  -3
3
1  -2  3

Sample Output

5
7
6

Explanation

After Query 1 : [ 0 , 3 , -2 ] => sum = 0 + 3 + 2 = 5

After Query 2 : [ -2 , 1 , -4 ] => sum = 2 + 1 + 4 = 7

After Query 3 : [ 1 , 4 , -1 ] => sum = 1 + 4 + 1 = 6

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int n,*a,q,*aq;
  long int sum=0;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);

  scanf("%d",&q);
  aq=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*q);
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&aq[i]);

  for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        sum+=abs(aq[i]+a[j]);
        a[j]=aq[i]+a[j];
    }

    printf("%ld\n",sum);
    sum=0;

  } 

}
```

Some test cases are timing out.

Comment: For each query, there may be numbers in the array that stay negative, change sign, and stay positive, respectively. If you do not follow Yves Daoust's (sly) suggestion to bin (sort, in one of the interpretations of that word) input values, think about ordering them (another meaning of *sort*). Keep a *value offset* to be modified by each query (don't update the array entries) and the index of the first non-negative entry. For each query, the latter will be one end of the range of "interesting entries" - search for `-x`(modified by the offset) for the other end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an outline of an algorithm:

Sample Input

```
3
-1 2 -3
```

Sort the data and compute prefix sums:

```
-3, -1, 2
-3, -4, -2 (prefix sums)
```

(Using a histogram as Yves Daoust [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53875794/2034787) would eliminate the initial sort and any binary search to find the three sections below, which would significantly optimise complexity.)

Maintain a running delta:

```
delta = 0
```

For each query of

```
1 -2 3
```

**Query 1:**

```
* update delta:
  delta = 0 + 1 = 1

* identify three sections:
  [negative unaffected] [switches sign] [positive unaffected]
       -3,   -1,                                 2

* Add for each section abs(num_elements * delta + prefix_sum):
   abs(2 * 1 + (-4 - 0))        +        abs(1 * 1 + (-2 -(-4)))
   = abs(2 - 4) + abs(1 + 2)
   = 5
```

**Query -2:**

```
* update delta:
  delta = 1 - 2 = -1

* identify three sections:
  [negative unaffected] [switches sign] [positive unaffected]
       -3,   -1,                                 2

* Add for each section abs(num_elements * delta + prefix_sum):
   abs(2 * (-1) + (-4 - 0))     +     abs(1 * (-1) + (-2 -(-4)))
   = abs(-2 - 4) + abs(-1 + 2)
   = 7
```

**Query 3:**

```
* update delta:
  delta = -1 + 3 = 2

* identify three sections:
  [negative unaffected] [switches sign] [positive unaffected]
       -3,                   -1,                   2

* Add for each section abs(num_elements * delta + prefix_sum):
 abs(1 * 2 + (-3 - 0)) + abs(1 * 2 + (-4 - (-3))) + abs(1 * 2 + (-2 -(-4)))
   = abs(2 - 3) + abs(2 - 1) + abs(2 + 2)
   = 6
```

Sample Output

```
5
7
6
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is performing N.Q operations, which is huge.

First notice that the range of the data is moderate, so that you can represent the N numbers using an histogram of 4001 entries. This histogram is computed in N operations (plus initializing the bins).

Then the requested sum is obtained as the sum of the absolute differences with every bin, weighted by the bin values. This lowers the workload from N.Q to B.Q (B is the number of bins).

---

If I am right, we can do much better by decomposing the sum in a subsum for the negative values and another in the positives. And these sums are obtained by computing prefix sums. This should lead to a solution in Q operations, after preprocessing the histogram in B operations.